# How to resolve the error "No living connection" while starting Kibana in windows

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk, kibana-7

I have just started to learn about the ELK stack. I am referring to this site
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/6.4/get-started-elastic-stack.html
for installing the ELK stack in my system I have a problem when I try to start Kibana in my windows system. I get the following error

```
\log   [13:36:52.255] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/                
log   [13:36:52.277] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] No living connections  
log   [13:36:52.279] [warning][task_manager] PollError No Living connections                                            
log   [13:36:53.810] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/
log   [13:36:53.836] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] No living connections                                              
log   [13:36:56.456] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/  
log   [13:36:56.457] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] No living connections                                              
log   [13:36:56.458] [warning][task_manager] PollError No Living connections 
log   [13:36:57.348] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/                
log   [13:36:57.349] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] No living connections
```

I think it is having a problem fetching the Elastic Search connection. But I think the elastic search instance has been started successfully. When I run

```
./bin/elasticsearch.bat
```

I get the following results

```
[2019-09-01T18:34:11,594][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP-TD85D7S] publish_address {192.168.0.101:9200}, bound_addresses {192.168.99.1:9200}, {192.168.56.1:9200}, {192.168.0.101:9200}   
[2019-09-01T18:34:11,595][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [DESKTOP-TD85D7S] started
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `kibana.yml` configuration file, you need to change the following line:

```
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
```

to

```
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://192.168.0.101:9200"]
```

Comment: Replacing localhost with the host's IP address is only useful if you're querying elasticsearch from another machine. however, by default, you want to query localhost.

Comment: @MaxiReglisse ok but just note that in production mode, you cannot query localhost

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Elasticsearch 7.4.0, Kibana 7.4.0**

***status: working.***

I am using a docker-compose.yml file to run elasticsearch and kibana on localhost. port 9200 is being used by another service so, I have mapped 9201:9200 (9201 of localhost with 9200 of docker container)

In kibana environment variable we are setting elasticsearch host and port (port should be of container port) eg. ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200

**File: docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  # Elasticsearch 
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9201:9200
      - 9300:9300

  # Kibana
  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.4.0
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
    driver: local
```

Elastic search is running at http://localhost:9201,  you will get similar to

```
{
  "name" : "d0bb78764b7e",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "Djch5nbnSWC-EqYawp2Cng",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.4.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "22e1767283e61a198cb4db791ea66e3f11ab9910",
    "build_date" : "2019-09-27T08:36:48.569419Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.2.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Kibana is running at http://localhost:5601, open in the browser.

**Note: if your docker is running on some server other than your local machine, then replace localhost, with that server host**

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in a log file: /var/log/elasticsearch/my-instance.log

```
[2022-07-25T15:59:44,049][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] 
[nextcloud] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[failed to bind service]; 
nested: AccessDeniedException[/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes];
```

you have to set the bit s on the folder /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes

```
# mkdir /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes
# chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes
# chmod g+s /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes
# ls -ltr /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes
drwxr-sr-x 5 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4096 25 juil. 16:42 0/
```

you can then query localhost on port 9200.

```
# curl http://localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "nextcloud",
  "cluster_name" : "my-instance",
  "cluster_uuid" : "040...V3TA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.14.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "66b...331e",
    "build_date" : "2021-08-26T09:01:05.390870785Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.9.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

My environment: Debian11.
I installed elasticsearch by hand, by downloading the package elasticsearch-7.14.1-amd64.deb

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.14.1-amd64.deb
```

hope it helps